# How to use Trello API without user authorization?

Tags: javascript, php, api, authorization, trello

I need to integrate a Trello API into Support System, but I don't want users see the typical popup saying "Do you want to allow this app?".
So, I need always the same user (me) by default for all connections (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE).

I would like when the user go to the Support System can see, add and update the tasks without do log in and without allow none (on Trello) and use my default user.

Don't mind if the solution is on the client-side or server-side.

Is there any way to make this?

Answer (score 0):

Generate an application key that is set to never expire. Use these credentials to interact with your board/list using server-side php scripts.

Your support system will then use these credentials internally to interact with the API.

Comment: How can I do that? I need to allow first the Trello API to get the "never expiration" token.

Answer (score 0):

As [Gadget](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4493444/gadget) mentioned, you can use a pre-generated access that never expires. Although it's the token and not the application key that never expires. Trello thise calls the "Authorize Route" (when the user must always confirm is standard OAuth1.)

[Trello describes here how to get one of those tokens.](https://developers.trello.com/authorize)

(I would comment this instead, but my reputation is too low.)

EDIT: [Here is Trello's description of how to do it with their JavaScript-library](https://developers.trello.com/clientjs)